# Find Python Multiplication from user input

Tags: python

Junior Python Coder here! Trying to print multiplication table with user input but stuck.

```py
min_num=1
max_num=11

starting_range = int(input ("Enter the minimum number: "))
ending_range = int(input ("Enter the maximum number: "))

print ("The Multiplication Table of: ", starting_range)    
for count in range(1, 11):      
   print (starting_range, 'x', count, '=', ending_range * count)

if max_num - min_num > 10 :
   print('invalid range ')
else:
   for num in range (min_num,max_num):
      print ("The Multiplication Table of: ", ending_range)
      for count in range(min_num, max_num):      
         print (starting_range, 'x', count, '=', ending_range * count)
```

Comment: Could you give an example of what your desired output would look like for example values of `starting_range` and `ending_range`?

Comment: Enter the minimum number: 1 
Enter the maximum number: 3

Multiplication Table of 1:
1 × 1 = 1
1 × 2 = 2
1 × 3 = 3
1 × 4 = 4
1 × 5 = 5
1 × 6 = 6
1 × 7 = 7
1 × 8 = 8
1 × 9 = 9
1 × 10 = 10
1 × 11 = 11
1 × 12 = 12

Multiplication Table of 2:
2 × 1 = 2
2 × 2 = 4
2 × 3 = 6
2 × 4 = 8
2 × 5 = 10
2 × 6 = 12
2 × 7 = 14
2 × 8 = 16
2 × 9 = 18
2 × 10 = 20
2 × 11 = 22
2 × 12 = 24

Multiplication Table of 3:
3 × 1 = 3
3 × 2 = 6
3 × 3 = 9
3 × 4 = 12
3 × 5 = 15
3 × 6 = 18
3 × 7 = 21
3 × 8 = 24
3 × 9 = 27
3 × 10 = 30
3 × 11 = 33
3 × 12 = 36

Comment: Hopefully that makes sense - sorry I'm a real novice!

Comment: Please put that example in the body of the question, suitably formatted :)  It is very helpful.  Is it intended to go up to 12 or only to 10?

Comment: Apologies having issues editing the post itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I really understand what you're trying to do as your code isn't formatted, but for a multiplication table, a nested loop is a solution.

The basic idea is: For every number in the given range, loop over the whole range and multiply it by each element. This will print the whole multiplication table.

```
start = 1 # You can change these to be inputted by the user.
end = 10

for i in range(start, end + 1): # We add 1 to the end because range() is exclusive on endpoint.
    for j in range(start, end + 1):
        print(f"{i} x {j} = {i * j}")
```

If you only need the table as something like:

15 x 1

15 x 2

15 x 3

...

You can do this with one loop:

```
num = 10

for i in range(1, num + 1):
    print(f"{num} x {i} = {num * i}")
```

I recommend you search up on F-strings in Python if you do not understand the print(f"..") parts. They're very convenient. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Minimal change to original code:

```py
min_num = 1
max_num = 11

starting_range = 4 # You can use int() and input() as in your original code to make this user defined.
ending_range = 7

# Removed the error checking, wasn't sure precisely what it was meant to do.
for num in range(starting_range,ending_range):
  print ("The Multiplication Table of: ", num)
  for count in range(min_num, max_num):      
     print (num, 'x', count, '=', num * count)
```

Try it at https://www.mycompiler.io/view/7JVNtxkT53k

This prints:

```
The Multiplication Table of:  4
4 x 1 = 4
4 x 2 = 8
4 x 3 = 12
4 x 4 = 16
4 x 5 = 20
4 x 6 = 24
4 x 7 = 28
4 x 8 = 32
4 x 9 = 36
4 x 10 = 40
The Multiplication Table of:  5
5 x 1 = 5
5 x 2 = 10
5 x 3 = 15
5 x 4 = 20
5 x 5 = 25
5 x 6 = 30
5 x 7 = 35
5 x 8 = 40
5 x 9 = 45
5 x 10 = 50
The Multiplication Table of:  6
6 x 1 = 6
6 x 2 = 12
6 x 3 = 18
6 x 4 = 24
6 x 5 = 30
6 x 6 = 36
6 x 7 = 42
6 x 8 = 48
6 x 9 = 54
6 x 10 = 60
```

Alternative code defining a function:

```py
def print_multiplication_table(n, max_value=11):
    if n > max_value or n <= 0:
        raise ValueError
    
    print(f"The Multiplication Table of: {n}")
    for m in range(1, max_value):
        print(f"{n} x {m} = {n*m}")

starting_range = 4 # You can use int() and input() as in your original code to make this user defined.
ending_range = 7

for i in range(starting_range, ending_range):
    print_multiplication_table(i)
```

Try it at https://www.mycompiler.io/view/1uttFLmFEiD

Comment: Thank you both for your help, lesson learnt for formatting next time!